# How can i change a function argument depending on the type of variable?

Tags: python

I have this piece of code i'm using for a telegram bot:

```
r = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/botMY_BOT_ID/sendPhoto?chat_id=MY_CHAT_ID",files=stuff)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

Theres any way to change the "files=stuff" to "data=stuff" depending on the type of "stuff"(bytes or string), without writing another requests line ?

Comment: Use a conditional, create a dictionary, splat the dictionary.

Comment: `type('this is a test')` vs `type(b'this is a test')`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dict` display that evaluates an expression to generate the correct keyword.

```
requests.post(..., **{kind_of_stuff(stuff): stuff})
```

where `kind_of_stuff` is a function that returns `'file'` or `'data'` as appropriate based on the type of `stuff`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed, i didn't know you could use a dict for arguments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
r = requests.post("...", **{"file":stuff} if //condition else {"data": stuff})
```